# Git/Heroku - How to hide my SECRET_KEY?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Im using Python and Django to create a Heroku web app and Heroku gives me this error after the command 'git push heroku master': `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlist.secret_settings'` when attempting to do this:

```
#settings.py
from .secret_settings import *  
# from secret_settings.py import * doesn't work for some reason.
```

Here is what secret_settings.py (which is in the same folder as settings.py) contains:

```
#secret_settings.py
SECRET_KEY = 'string here'
```

The problem is, this works when I test my web app on my local server (ie http://127.0.0.1:8000/), but its not working when I push these changes to Heroku. All I want to do is hide my SECRET_KEY, per others advice, as you can see. Ive looked at others suggestions and I can't seem to figure it out, choosing this method because it was understandable. Very frustrating. Beginner friendly answers/steps are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm guessing you've configured Git to ignore `secret_settings.py`. That's the only reason I can think of to create a separate file.

Heroku deploys are powered by Git. Since `secret_settings.py` isn't tracked by Git it doesn't get pushed to Heroku. You could add the file to your repository, but that would defeat the purpose of having a separate untracked file in the first place.

The solution is to use an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). This is [well-supported on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

In your `settings.py` file, set your `SECRET_KEY` using [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) like this:

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'Optional default value')
```

This tells Django to load your `SECRET_KEY` setting from an environment variable called `SECRET_KEY`. If no such environment variable exists it will fall back to the optional default value. On your development machine it's probably fine to use the default.

Finally, set the `SECRET_KEY` environment variable on Heroku. You can do this by running [`heroku config:set SECRET_KEY="YOUR_SECRET_KEY_VALUE"`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) on your development machine, or via Heroku's web-based dashboard.

Your `secret_settings.py` file is no longer required.

Comment: Thanks Chris that helps immensely, the documentation wasn't clear to me. One follow up question is if its secure to include my original `SECRET_KEY` in the second argument in `os.getenv` (ie the Optional default value) if I'm committing it to a public repo? If its not secure should I just use `SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')` in `settings.py`? I guess the question really is if the 1st argument in `os.getenv` is the **only** authentic `SECRET_KEY` on the web app if its included, but if its not included and your on the development machine, it will instead use the second argument?

Comment: @reedx8, if you include your real secret key as the second argument it will be visible to the world in your public repository. That's probably not what you want. You can use `os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')`, but then you'll need to set a `SECRET_KEY` environment variable in _all_ of your environments (your development machine, any test or staging environments you may have, etc.). It's probably easier to include a dummy value as a default value, though of course it's possible to set environment variables everywhere. I've added a link to the docs for `os.getenv()`.