# Is it safe to put secret key in heroku config

Tags: heroku, secret-key

regarding this post:
[Git/Heroku - How to hide my SECRET_KEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949022/git-heroku-how-to-hide-my-secret-key/63062854?noredirect=1#comment111518993_63062854)

follow up question here:

when you set:  heroku config:set SECRET_KEY="..."

there is no way for a third party to access the entered secret key, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the example provided they are setting the secret using an `operating system (OS)` environment variable. The only way for someone to access your secret key is if it's exposed to the client-side or they have access to your dyno or your OS.

Using heroku environment variables is incredibly secure and there's really nothing to worry about in this instance.